# UISegmentedControl in UIToolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5, uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm migrating an App from iOS 4 to iOS 5 and I find myself stuck. Here's my problem:

I have a `UIToolbar` that has a `UISegmentedControl` within. Now, with the old App, I used all the methods of `UISegmentedControl`, like

```
[switch removeAllSegments];
```

but this leads to crash in the new iOS 5 because now the `UISegmentedControl` is automatically converted in `UIBarButtonItem`.
How can I solve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This may not best practice. But i think you have to add subview on UIToolbar and in that subview please add segmented controls. May it work for you.

Comment: I wrote: segCont = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] init] autorelease];
    oggetti = [[centralToolbar items] mutableCopy];
    [oggetti removeObjectAtIndex:1];
    [oggetti insertObject:segCont atIndex:1];
    [centralToolbar setItems:oggetti]; 
But it still crash.